# As done the research put the name in the title in datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have the following table where I print with datatables.

```js
var cars = [
   {nome:  "Teste", Discricao:  "Teste1",},
   {nome:  "Teste2", Discricao:  "Teste3",},
];

$(function () { 
  $('.cons-assid').on("click", function() {
    $("#consultassid tbody").empty();
          
      var linha = ``; 

        $('.consultassid > tbody > tr').remove();
        var colab = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        colab = cars[i].nome;
        linha += `<tr">
                      <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${cars[i].nome}</td>
                      <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${cars[i].Discricao}</td>
                    </tr>`;
                    
      }
                    
      $("#consultassid tbody").html(linha);

      $('.consultassid').dataTable({ 
        dom: 'Bflrtip',
        "pagingType": "full_numbers", 
        "iDisplayLength": 10,                          
        "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "Aguarde enquanto os dados são carregados ...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registos por página",
        "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registo correspondente ao criterio encontrado",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Exibindo 0 a 0 de 0 registos",
        "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registos",
        "sInfoFiltered": "",
        "sSearch": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>",
        "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst":    "<i class='fa fa-fast-backward' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
          "sPrevious": "<i class='fa fa-backward' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>",
          "sNext":     "<i class='fa fa-forward' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
          "sLast":     "<i class='fa fa-fast-forward' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
          }
        },
        buttons: [
          {
              extend: 'print',
                      text: 'print',
                      title: '<div style="text-align: left;">Colaborador:  ' +colab+  '</div>',
                      exportOptions: {
                          columns: function ( idx, data, node ) {
                            if (idx >= 4) {
                                return data;
                            }
                          }
                        },
                      customize: function ( win ) {
                          $(win.document.body)
                              .css( 'font-size', '12pt' );
        
                          $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                              .addClass( 'compact' )
                              .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                      }
          }
        ]
      });   
      
    });
  });
  
  $(function() {
    $(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      el = $(this).data('element');
      $(el).show();
      $("section > div").not(el).hide();
    });
});
  
$(function() {
    $(".btn-hide").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      el = $(this).data('element');
      $(el).hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

<a href="s103" data-element="#minhaDiv103" class="btn-show cons-assid">
    <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-wristwatch"></i>
    Assiduidade
</a>
<section id="s103">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv103">
    <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover consultassid" id="consultassid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Colaborador</th>
                <th class="text-center">Serviço</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

After returning the table, the search field of the datatables itself appears. So if you search for a name of a contributor, I want the title when printing to return the name of that contributor.
The way I have it, the name of the last contributor returns in the title after running the for, and it should return the name I put in the search field.

Can you help to solve this problem?

Comment: the `data` variable is not defined anywhere

Comment: @diegod I have already completed the question, is it better to also put the query to the database?

Comment: a question should be as clear as possible so that people have all the needed information to face the problem. Such code cannot run because the `data` variable is undefined and it's too hard to reverse its logic for the sake of answering a question. No you shouldn't put the query to the database.. you should put a sample of data already populated that will make that code runnable per se. I mean if you wish to raise the chance to receive a meaningful feedback. By the way after you edited the question, the code has a syntax error

Comment: @diegod 
Thanks for the tip. I already paste it in order to work and test. If searching for test when printing it shows the name test2, which is the last line returned. I wanted it to return the name I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "*it should return the name I put in the search field*".

If you want to print the text that the user entered into the search field, you need to use a function instead of a static string.

You are using this:

```js
title: '<div style="text-align: left;">Colaborador:  ' +colab+  '</div>',
```

Change it to this:

```
title: function () {
  let colab = $( 'input.form-control' ).val();
  return '<div style="text-align: left;">Colaborador:  ' +  colab +  '</div>';
}
```

When you use a hard-coded string, that value is calculated when the web page first loads, and then it is never re-calculated. DataTables always uses the same value.

But if you use a function in your DataTable's `title` option, that function is re-executed every time you print the table.

You will probably want to enhance the above code, to deal with cases where the user does not type anything (empty string).

---

In your question you also say "*I want the title when printing to return the name of that contributor*". That is different from "*the name I put in the search field*". If you type `teste3`, then the printout will display `Colaborador: Teste3` - which is *not* the name of that record's contributor (the name is `Teste2`).

So the question is not completely clear - but I think using the function is the answer you need.